# Rails set school attribute based on users email address?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, email, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails app I have a regex that ensures only @uw.edu or @berkeley.edu email addresses can be used at user#registration. What I'd like to do now is automatically set the school that the user goes to based on which of those domains is the one in their email address. So if, for example, someone signs up with a @berkeley.edu email, the school attribute in the User model will be set to "University of California, Berkeley."

I've tried doing this but it seems to be a non-trivial problem. Here's what the regex in the User model looks like (I haven't added UW.edu yet, but you get the idea):

```
berkeley_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@berkeley\.edu\z/i
validates :email, :presence => true, :format => {:with => berkeley_regex}
```

I also already have added a "school" column to the User model. If anyone can show me how to do what I want to do that'd be awesome.

I tried this:

```
def match
    matches = User['email'].match(/(?<uw>.*?uw\.edu)|((?<berk>.*?berkeley\.edu))/i)
    school = 'uw' if matches['uw'].present?
    school = 'berk' if matches['berkeley'].present?
  end
```

and before_validation :match at the top, but it gives me the error

undefined method `[]' for #Class:0x008fe1a995

Using before_save results in the same. How do I get the email of the user as they're signing up?

Answer (score 1):

why u not doing something like  this in a before_save hook

```
matches = params['email'].match(/(?<uw>.*?uw\.edu)|((?<berk>.*?berkeley\.edu))/i)
school = 'uw' if matches['uw'].present?
school = 'berk' if matches['berkeley'].present?
```

and ur done?

Comment: User['email'] is not the way u access the current_user in the model. use self.email.match